# How to select all rows on Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to delete all the rows that I don't need on Google Sheets, my data has a table header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to select all rows using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function muFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C:C").activate();
}
```

- When this script is run, the column "C" of "Sheet1" is selected.
- For example, when "C:C" is modified to "C2:C", the cells "C2:C" are selected.

#### Note:

- From `I want to delete all the rows that I don't need on Google Sheets, my data has a table header.`, when you want to clear the rows except for the 1st header row, you can also use the following script. When the following script is run, the cells "C2:C" of "Sheet1" are cleared.

  ```
    function muFunction2() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("C2:C").clearContent();
    }
  ```
- From `What's the code equivalent for Command + shift + down?`, in this case, I thought that the following script is the result you expect? When you use the following script, please select a cell and run the script. By this, the rows of the data range after the selected cell are selected.

  ```
    function myFunction3() {
      const activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
      activeRange.offset(0, 0, activeRange.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() - activeRange.getRow() + 1).activate();
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)